# Ionic push: App breaks when push logic is inside the controller

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, push-notification

**THE SITUATION:**

I am implementing Ionic Push for my Ionic app.

I already did all the setup and registration and everything is working fine. 
I have already tested it and send a curl request on the device (both ios and android) and I am properly receive the notification.

So what?

I need to move the push logic inside the controller. 
So i can retrieve the registrationId and save it in a table along with other user data. In order to use it later when needed.

But when i move from the code from the .run() in the app.js to the controller the app crash..

**THE ERROR:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.js:5844:47
```

**THE CODE:**

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
    "debug": true
});

push.register(function(token) {  
    console.log("My Device token:",token.token);
    alert(token.token);
    push.saveToken(token);  // persist the token in the Ionic Platform 
});
```

**THE QUESTION:**

I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

The same code inside `$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {}` it works fine but not in controller...

I have already test the same logic in a fresh app and I could indeed put that logic in the controller.

Do you have some ideas why this time i can't?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You said "The same code inside $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {} it works fine but not in controller...". Have you tried to put your in controller with `$ionicPlatform.ready` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried inside that and injecting $ionicPlatform but i get the same error

Comment: I get that error when dev_push is set to false and I serve the app in a browser. Try running ``ionic config set dev_push true`` if you're running ``ionic serve``

Comment: No. Unfortunately i get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found a solution.

I had to leave the push logic inside the run() method. Reading around it seems that's the way to go.

The solution was quite simple:

Injecting $rootScope inside the run method and use it to store the registrationId.

After that you can do whatever you want with it, for example send a post request to your api and save in db.

**THE CODE:**

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    var push = new Ionic.Push({
        "debug": true
    });

    push.register(function(token) {

        console.log("My Device token:",token.token);

        push.saveToken(token);  // persist the token in the Ionic Platform

        $rootScope.registrationId = token.token;  !! <-- 

    });

  });
})
```